# Phonon can read .avi files on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, avi, phonon

I try to read a .avi file on MacOS X with Phonon and Qt. But I can't. Even in QtDemo, the "Media Player" is not able to display those kind of file. Is there a way to make it work ?

Comment: Have you tried installing [Perian](http://perian.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing the right codecs to the system. "avi" is actually just a container file format that can contain media encoded with many possible audio and video codecs, that might not be supported/installed by default in OS-X. Phonon itself doesn't provide media decoding capabilities, it uses whatever is available on the system or separately configured as it's back end.

Comment: I can open and play avi file with VLC, so I guess the codec is installed. Maybe there is a way to tell Phonon what codec use ?

Comment: VLC uses it's own codecs that are not available system wide for other applications to use. There is however a VLC backend for Phonon also, but that won't work simply by you having the VLC application installed. I don't unfortunately have more details about the VLC backend for Phonon.